# Frontend is taking too much CPU

Tags: system

On running top, I see a command called "frontend" has been running for 100+ hours and it is taking half of my CPU resource. What does it do?

Comment: `man frontend;man -k frontend;type -p frontend; locate frontend;dpkg -S $(type -p frontend);pgrep frontend`

Comment: I met the same issue. Fixed by following:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181159/cpu-running-much-harder-louder-after-software-update/1214382#1214382