# How to investigate an unknown process called `frontend` pegging CPU all the time

Tags: 18.04, cpu, process, top

As my laptop (Dell precision 16Gb, ubuntu 18.4) had been slower than usual, I had a look at `top`.
Here I have a process, called `frontend` pegging 50% of the CPU.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 7189 root      20   0  111508  22584   7440 S  44.9  0.1   0:12.23 frontend
```

I have no clue of what it can be, and it is not a process started by my user as `ps -u`whoami`| grep frontend` returned nothing. It is also there after restarting and `kill 7189` asks me for superuser permission, reason why I do not think that a simple `sudo kill` would solve the issue. Though I have not tried yet.

Anyone has any help, suggestion, idea about what to do? Anyone heard about a virus that can cause that?

Comment: It may be related to an UEFI update I recently made: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181159/cpu-running-much-harder-louder-after-software-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, check this answer given in a similar situation, the system might be waiting for a secure boot: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554025/linux-mint-frontend-process-what-is-it

Comment: Yes, it is! Sorry for the duplicate, for some reasons I could not find the answer googling it...!