# update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key running on start up dont want to disable secure boot what to do?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

the command `/usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /usr/sbin/update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key` runs on startup eating ~50% cpu and ~20% mem i can kill it manualy but i want to solve that problem.

It started when i installed VMware player wich i have unistalled since yet it still remains when i dont use secure boot diffrent prosses run and eat ~20% cpu constently at idle.

Before that whole thing i used max of 2% cpu.

can i sign the MOK or what ever to get rid of this or what do i have to do?

Edit:

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Xubuntu install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and a solution can be found on this page:
[CPU running much harder/louder after software update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181159/cpu-running-much-harder-louder-after-software-update)

In short, you have to kill the process, as you have, and then start it manually from a command line.

The problem seems to be that the dialog to complete the MOK setup is not displayed. After entering a suitable password you should reboot and then enroll the MOK during boot.